React bootstrap causes build failed
I'm working on a Nextjs project with React bootstrap. It was working fine until today, somehow all of the React bootstrap components are returning the same error and causing build errors.
'Dropdown.Item' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.ts(2786)

No changes were made at all to the package.json or any config files. The following are dependencies regarding React, Next, TS, and React bootstrap|
"@types/react": "18.0.30",
"@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
"next": "13.2.4",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"typescript": "5.0.2",


Which version of react-bootstrap you have installed? There is a very fresh issue on their github that can be related to problem you have.

I had this issue.  there are 2 solutions one is to use the 2.10.2 version as the 2.11 was causing me issues and the other is the legacy run build command.  One project I am having this issue the first worked the other it did not so looking for the legacy command myself.  I will post an update when I get the other project fixed.

If you're planning to update the question, the best update is to edit the existing answer rather than posting a new answer. Answers should emphasise how to solve a problem, over any problems that you are having.
